# STM32F103 Input Capture Too Slow

Tags: stm32

I have a high speed clock at 10 MHz going to the processor's TIM4 input capture pin (ch.3). I would like to verify that the clock is running at 10 MHz with the processor's input capture. I coded the processor with the input capture module, and it works fine for lower frequencies (around 1 kHz or so). Once I start to climb the frequency up to the MHz range, the processor starts to miss interrupts and thus gives me an incorrect frequency. I didn't see anywhere in the datasheet that states the maximum frequency that the input capture can read. I have an external clock of 8 MHz, and a core clock of 72 MHz, so I would imagine that I can read a 10 MHz signal. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the `TIM_ICInitStructure.TIM_ICPrescaler` options. Usually you'll have it set to `TIM_ICPSC_DIV1` so that interrupts are generated on every valid transition.

Prescaler values of 1,2,4 and 8 are available that will allow you to effictively reduce the rate of interrupt generation by that factor. For example, for a 10MHz signal with a prescaler of 8 you'd expect to count a frequency of 10Mhz/8 = 1.25MHz.

This is still quite tight for a 72MHz HCLK so you'll still need to optimise your IRQ handler carefully.

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you're generating an interrupt request for every rising (or falling) edge of the clock.

If that is indeed the case, then think about this for a second: with a 10 MHz input signal, you're generating an interrupt about every 7 CPU cycles. In these 7 CPU cycles, you need to budget time to save registers to RAM, run the IRQ handler function prolog, run the actual code you wrote for the interrupt handler, run the IRQ handler function epilogue, and restore the registers.

Best case, if you set compiler flags to optimize for speed and you're not doing much processing in the interrupt handler, you're looking at tens of cycles to run all these tasks. Since you only have 7 cycles to run tens of cycles' worth of processing, it's no surprise that you're missing interrupts.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use an interrupt routine at that frequency. You need to feed the 10MHz in as an external trigger to the timer. Then you can use the prescaler and the timer to divide down to a suitable lower interrupt frequency.